# Use ROS bloom to generate a deb and a -dev.deb packages

Tags: deb, ros2, bloom

I have implemented a library with some functionalities. As an example, let's say [this](https://bitbucket.org/apalomeriqua/library_cpp_package/src/master/) is my library. Whenever I compile with:

```
mkdir build
cmake ..
make
```

and install this library:

```
sudo make install
```

another package can find it and use it.

Now I want to create Debian packages for this library. If I use the ROS approach (bloom) with:

```
bloom-generate debian --os-name ubuntu --os-version jammy
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

A binary package is created and if I install it everything looks ok. However, I want to create instead of one package, two, one for the runtime library and one for the development tools, in this way, clients that are not developing new apps on top of the library do not need to install all the headers, cmakes, etc.

Is there any way of doing such a thing? I would like to stick to ROS bloom as it simplifies a lot the packaging dependency (both runtime and build time).

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at known packages in ROS that achieve the same thing that you want. They probably have the pipeline available for you to inspect. maybe `ros_navigation` and `moveit`

Answer (score 0):

Packing two project isn't possible AFAIK (and I checked).
I had the same issue - eventually I was able to combine my two packages into one(with the same Cmake).
See https://answers.ros.org/question/411859/adding-custom-message-to-existing-package-humble-ubuntu22-fails/
for more details.

Hope this helps.